# go/kubernetes - runtime.notRegisteredErr

Tags: go, kubernetes

I'm doing some unit testing and part of the function does this -

```
    o := &corev1.Secret{}
    if err := c.Scheme.Convert(c.Object, o, nil); err != nil {
        return o, err
    }
```

When I'm running the unit test it's throwing this error `&runtime.notRegisteredErr{schemeName:"pkg/runtime/scheme.go:101", gvk:schema.GroupVersionKind{Group:"", Version:"v1", Kind:"secret"}, target:runtime.GroupVersioner(nil)`

even though I generate a new schema with CoreV1 Secret & SecretList

```
func schemeGet() *runtime.Scheme {
    s := runtime.NewScheme()
    s.AddKnownTypes(corev1.SchemeGroupVersion,
        &corev1.Secret{},
        &corev1.SecretList{},
    )
    return s
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think the right way is create a `Mock` of `runtime.Scheme`  tests will be more independent.